# When I add my jquery ( <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>) my sidebar doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!-- Start Head with full tags -->
<?php $this->load->view('admin/elements/head');?>

<!-- start nav of dashboard-->
<?php $this->load->view('admin/dashboard/main_head_dashboard');?>

<!-- start aside bar of dashboard -->
<?php $this->load->view('admin/dashboard/aside_dashboard');?>

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
         <?php $this->load->view('admin/elements/theme_control');?>
         <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
         <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
            immediately after the control sidebar -->
         <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
      <!-- ./wrapper -->

      <?php $this->load->view('admin/elements/footerscript');?>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/form/dist/jquery.simplewizard.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#wizard1").simpleWizard({
                cssClassStepActive: "active",
                cssClassStepDone: "done",
                onFinish: function() {
                    alert("Wizard finished")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>


      <script>
         $("#radio1").click(function(){

         $("#addressHide").addClass('hide_toggle');
         });

         $("#radio2").click(function(){
         $('#addressHide').removeClass('hide_toggle');
         show_map();


            });



      </script>
      <script>
         function show_map()
         {

                var lat = 37.279518,
                 lng = -121.867905,
                    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

                //zoomControl: true,
                //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                    zoom: 13,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    panControl: true,
                    panControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                    },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
                    }
                },
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: image 
                    });

                var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
                    types: ["geocode"]
                });

                autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
                    infowindow.close();
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);
                    }

                    moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
                    $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                    $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
                    $('.MapPlace').val(place.geometry.location.placeName());

                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                    $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
                    $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
                    infowindow.close();
                            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                            geocoder.geocode({
                                "latLng":event.latLng
                            }, function (results, status) {
                                console.log(results, status);
                                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                    console.log(results);
                                    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                        lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                        placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                                    moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                                    $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                }
                            });
                });

                function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
                    marker.setIcon(image);
                    marker.setPosition(latlng);
                    infowindow.setContent(placeName);
                    //infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

         }
      </script>
      <script>
         $(function () {
             var lat = 37.279518,
                 lng = -121.867905,
                 latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                 image = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png';

             //zoomControl: true,
             //zoomControlOptions: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,

             var mapOptions = {
                 center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                 zoom: 13,
                 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                 panControl: true,
                 panControlOptions: {
                     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
                 },
                 zoomControl: true,
                 zoomControlOptions: {
                     style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                     position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_left
                 }
             },
             map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions),
                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: latlng,
                     map: map,
                     icon: image
                 });

             var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
             var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
                 types: ["geocode"]
             });

             autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
             var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

             google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (event) {
                 infowindow.close();
                 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                 if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                     map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                 } else {
                     map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                     map.setZoom(17);
                 }

                 moveMarker(place.name, place.geometry.location);
                 $('.MapLat').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
                 $('.MapLon').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
                 $('.MapPlace').val(place.geometry.location.placeName());

             });
             google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                 $('.MapLat').val(event.latLng.lat());
                 $('.MapLon').val(event.latLng.lng());
                 infowindow.close();
                         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                         geocoder.geocode({
                             "latLng":event.latLng
                         }, function (results, status) {
                             console.log(results, status);
                             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                 console.log(results);
                                 var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                                     lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng(),
                                     placeName = results[0].address_components[0].long_name,
                                     latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                                 moveMarker(placeName, latlng);
                                 $("#searchTextField").val(results[0].formatted_address);
                             }
                         });
             });

             function moveMarker(placeName, latlng) {
                 marker.setIcon(image);
                 marker.setPosition(latlng);
                 infowindow.setContent(placeName);
                 //infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
         });
      </script>
    <script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = 
          [
            '<img style="height: 75px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px" src="', 
            e.target.result,
            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), 
            '"/>'
          ].join('');

          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  //document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false); 
    </script>
```

Comment: make sure that you do not include jquery twice and different version

Comment: Check browser console, seems your jquery is conflicting with cloudflar and Jquery CDNs

Comment: Use the same version of jquery that you use for the validate plugin.

Comment: ye I have included jquery twice